# Pygame Flappy Bird Collision

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, collision

I'm making a flappy bird clone game and I'm trying to collide the bird with the pipe. I don't receive any error messages just the print("collision") is not showing when the bird hits the upper pipe. The problem is in the class `MainWindow`!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("FlapPY Bird")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# --> variables
FPS = 60

# classes
class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.Main()

    def Main(self):
        loop = True

        bird_width = 25
        bird_height = 25
        self.bird_x = 150
        self.bird_y = HEIGHT/2 - int(bird_height/2)
        bird_x_move = 0
        bird_y_move = 0
        pipe_spacing = 350
        pipe_speed = 1

        space = 100
        p1_x = 300
        p1_y = 400
        p1_w = 50
        p1_h = HEIGHT

        p2_x = p1_x + pipe_spacing
        p2_y = 250
        p2_w = 50
        p2_h = HEIGHT

        p3_x = p2_x + pipe_spacing
        p3_y = 250
        p3_w = 50
        p3_h = HEIGHT

        pipe1 = Pipes(p1_x, p1_y, p1_w, p1_h, space, pipe_speed, red)
        pipe2 = Pipes(p2_x, p2_y, p2_w, p2_h, space, pipe_speed, green)
        pipe3 = Pipes(p3_x, p3_y, p3_w, p3_h, space, pipe_speed, blue)

        while loop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                #print(event)
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        bird_y_move = -7

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        bird_y_move = 3

            screen.fill(white)

            self.bird_x += bird_x_move
            self.bird_y += bird_y_move
            bird = FlappyBird(self.bird_x, self.bird_y, bird_width, bird_height)
            bird.draw()

            pipe1.draw_pipes()
            pipe2.draw_pipes()
            pipe3.draw_pipes()

            pipe1.check_if()
            pipe2.check_if()
            pipe3.check_if()

            p1_new_x = pipe1.pipe_move()
            p2_new_x = pipe2.pipe_move()
            p3_new_x = pipe3.pipe_move()


            if self.bird_y <= p1_y - space and self.bird_y >= p1_y and self.bird_x+bird_width >= p1_new_x and self.bird_x <= p1_new_x+p1_w:
                print("collision")

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(FPS)

class FlappyBird(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


class Pipes(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, space, speed, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.space = space
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color

    def draw_pipes(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y-self.space-self.height, self.width, self.height))

    def pipe_move(self):
        self.x -= self.speed
        return self.x

    def check_if(self):
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 1000

MainWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the problem? What error messages do you receive? You ask for clemency, but do not provide the basic information we need to solve the problem...

Comment: I removed that long preamble - makes the question harder to read. But... as @darthbith pointed out: there's no actual question, just a code dump.

Comment: Im sorry for such a short question the code

 if self.bird_y <= p1_y - space and self.bird_y >= p1_y and self.bird_x+bird_width >= p1_new_x and self.bird_x <= p1_new_x+p1_w:
            print("collision")

isnt working and i do not know why please help.

Comment: Please please *please* edit your question with code. Don't ever put code in comments - completely unreadable.

Comment: 2 hints: 1. Start with a piece of (graph) paper and draw out the shapes when they collide and don't collide, with coordinates. 2. Sometimes it's easier to work out when they don't collide.

Comment: Thanks i really aprecciate @Glenn Rogers

Comment: Quick tip: To format your code correctly for SO, select it in the submission window and press Ctrl-K. That adds four extra spaces before each line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Do you even indent? :/</strike>

EDIT: It's fixed.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 600

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("FlapPY Bird")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# colors
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)

# --> variables
FPS = 60

# classes


class MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, w, h):
        self.width = w
        self.height = h
        self.Main()

    def Main(self):
        loop = True

        bird_width = 25
        bird_height = 25.0
        self.bird_x = 150
        self.bird_y = ((HEIGHT / 2) - int(bird_height / 2.0))
        bird_x_move = 0
        bird_y_move = 0
        pipe_spacing = 350
        pipe_speed = 1

        space = 100
        p1_x = 300
        p1_y = 400
        p1_w = 50
        p1_h = HEIGHT

        p2_x = p1_x + pipe_spacing
        p2_y = 250
        p2_w = 50
        p2_h = HEIGHT

        p3_x = p2_x + pipe_spacing
        p3_y = 250
        p3_w = 50
        p3_h = HEIGHT

        pipe1 = Pipes(p1_x, p1_y, p1_w, p1_h, space, pipe_speed, red)
        pipe2 = Pipes(p2_x, p2_y, p2_w, p2_h, space, pipe_speed, green)
        pipe3 = Pipes(p3_x, p3_y, p3_w, p3_h, space, pipe_speed, blue)

        while loop:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                #print(event)
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()

                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        bird_y_move = -7

                if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                        bird_y_move = 3

            screen.fill(white)

            self.bird_x += bird_x_move
            self.bird_y += bird_y_move
            bird = FlappyBird(self.bird_x, self.bird_y, bird_width, bird_height)
            bird.draw()

            pipe1.draw_pipes()
            pipe2.draw_pipes()
            pipe3.draw_pipes()

            pipe1.check_if()
            pipe2.check_if()
            pipe3.check_if()

            p1_new_x = pipe1.pipe_move()
            p2_new_x = pipe2.pipe_move()
            p3_new_x = pipe3.pipe_move()


            if (self.bird_y <= (p1_y - space)) and (self.bird_y <= p1_y) and ((self.bird_x + bird_width) >= p1_new_x) and (self.bird_x <= (p1_new_x + p1_w)):
                print("collision")
                break # If you don't break the loop, it will keep printing "collision" to the terminal
                exit(0) # Just in case.

            pygame.display.update()
            clock.tick(FPS)

class FlappyBird(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


class Pipes(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, space, speed, color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.space = space
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color

    def draw_pipes(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y-self.space-self.height, self.width, self.height))

    def pipe_move(self):
        self.x -= self.speed
        return self.x

    def check_if(self):
        if self.x < 0:
            self.x = 1000

MainWindow(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

Not really sure if this is how you want it, but it works.
What I did was change `self.bird_y >= p1_y` to `self.bird_y <= p1_y`

Comment: I am such a stupid programmer :( im litteraly crying now

Comment: Don't be so harsh to yourself. Programming is difficult and it takes a lot of time and effort to become good. We all make mistakes all the time, but it's important to see your mistakes as an opportunity to learn something new and a chance to improve yourself and your work, not as a failure. If you get completely stuck during a programming or debugging session, maybe try to do something completely different instead or sleep a night and then come back to the program and the problem will often be a lot clearer.